# Unsure what happening with my terminal but I'm getting a weird response

Tags: python, macos, shell, terminal, zsh

Whenever I run a python file, (vs code) or even open my terminal on mac I get a warning saying.

```
/Users/ABC/.zshrc:1: command not found: “alias
/Users/ABC/.zshrc:2: command not found: “alias
/Users/ABC/.zshrc:3: command not found: “alias
```

I looked it up and apparently zsh is a "shell" and is default for macs. How do I stop this from coming up in my terminal and why is it occuring in the first place.

Comment: Your `.zshrc` file is incorrectly formatted, looks like you have a quote character at the beginning of some line(s) where they shouldn't be

Comment: I don't think I've ever interfered with this file before, so how would this issue arise. Also, how would I be able to change this, where is this file typically located? Also thanks for the quick response

Comment: The file is in your home directory `~/.zshrc`, you can edit it with what ever program you would usually use for editing text. Some programs will modify this file to enable autocompletion for their command line tools, it's possible some installer messed it up

Comment: its saying "zsh: permission denied:" any ideas on another way to do this?

Comment: this is also coming up now. zsh: no such file or directory:

Comment: We can't know what you changed. Please include the problematic file (as text, not picture, video, or an interpetative Lego sculpture etc) and explain what you have changed recently.

Comment: You know the filename ( ~/.zshrc), you know the line numbers of the error (lines 1, 2 and 3), so why don't you post the complete offending lines?